# How to write regex to extract FlickR Image ID From URL?

Tags: asp.net, regex, flickr

I'm looking to do do two things, and I am looking to do them in a beautiful way. I am working on a project that allows users to upload flickr photos by simply entering their flickr image URL.  Ex: `http://www.flickr.com/photos/xdjio/226228060/`

I need to:

- make sure it is a URL that matches the following format: `http://www.flickr.com/photos/[0]/[1]/`
- extract the following part: `http://www.flickr.com/photos/xdjio/[0]/`

Now I could very easily write some string methods to do the above but I think it would be messy and love learning how to do these things in regex. Although not being a regex ninja I am currently unable to do the above.

Comment: something is happening with the URL's its meant to be (without spaces):
http://www.flickr.com/photos/xdjio/ 226228060 /

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given an input string with a URL like the one you provided, this will extract the image ID for any arbitrary user:

```
string input = "http://www.flickr.com/photos/xdjio/226228060/";
Match match = Regex.Match(input, "photos/[^/]+/(?<img>[0-9]+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.SingleLine);
if(match.Success)
{
    string imageID = match.Groups["img"].Value;
}
```

Breaking it down, we are searching for "photos/" followed by one or more characters that is not a '/', followed by a /, followed by one or more characters that are numbers. We also put the numbers segment into a named group called "img".

Comment: What about just splitting the path and get the third element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

thought i would add to this that when using the javascript asp.net validator it doesn't support the grouping name.

the regex to use in this situation would be:

```
photos/[^/]+/([0-9]+)
```

thought someone might find this useful